# Region detection opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

i have  a probleme  to  detecte the  principale  region of  a trafic sign my probleme  is  how to  extract the  Interior region in my project
this what  i have

[image]

i wan to change  the black circle to white color and all  the  other to black color  i tryed  this function  but it  doesn't work

```
Mat MainWindow::region (Mat img ){bool chacolBN=false;Mat res ;img.copyTo(res);



for(int i =0; i< img.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j < img.cols; j++)
    {
       if (img.at<uchar>(i,j) !=255&&img.at<uchar>(i,j+1) == 255)
       {
           chacolBN= true;
       }
       if (img.at<uchar>(i,j) ==255&&img.at<uchar>(i,j+1) !=255)
       {
           chacolBN= false;
       }
        if (chacolBN= true)
        {
            if(img.at<uchar>(i,j) ==255)
            {
                img.at<uchar>(i,j) =0;
            }
            else
            {
                img.at<uchar>(i,j) =255;
            }
        }


    }
}
return img;}
```

Comment: You should detect the contours of your Image.http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html With these you are able to find a Bounding Rectangle of your circle contour and that will be your region of interest you just color white.

Comment: thanks  David can you explane to me how  to  color  it with white color

Comment: When you get the rectangle coordinates use the following function:http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle For the color value you should choose 255 and thickness should be -1 or CV_FILLED and every Pixel within the rectangle will be drawn white.